# NullPointerException when calling a method reference to an arbitrary object with null argument

Tags: java, method-reference

I was trying to create a method reference to an arbitrary object, so I defined the following types:

```
interface I {
    boolean get(Impl impl);
}

static class Impl {
    public boolean get() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then I declared the method reference, like below:

```
I i = Impl::get;
```

When I call:

```
i.get(null);
```

I get a NullPointerException:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Can someone explain why this happens even though the `Impl` reference is not used anywhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you misunderstood the meaning of this line:

```
I i = Impl::get;
```

`I` is a functional interface that represents a method that takes an `Impl` and returns a `boolean`, whereas `get` is a method that takes no parameters and returns a `boolean`. How does this conversion work? Well, the compiler realises that `get` is an *instance* method, and to call it you must need a `Impl` object. Isn't that just like a function having a parameter before it is called?

So the compiler can happily infer that you meant:

```
I i = impl -> impl.get();
```

Now the cause of the NPE should be clear.

In general, all instance methods can be thought of as static methods that take one extra parameter, of type `T` where `T` is the declaring type of that instance method.

Comment: Is there an actual conversion by the compiler from method references to lambda expressions or is this just a logical mapping?

Comment: @mrboieng this is just logical mapping. The bytecode for method references is different.